# None is not being constructed with either NewObject, NewNamedObject or ConstructObject... but it is

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm initialising a UObject by using NewObject however when I run my project it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using RoomGenerator as an Actor and basic class yet am still getting the same error.

Function being called:

```
void ADungeonGenerator::GenerateDungeon()
{
    URoomGenerator* roomGenerator = NewObject<URoomGenerator>();
    roomGenerator->Init(5, 5, 5, 5);

    ARoom* room = roomGenerator->GenerateRoom();
}
```

RoomGenerator Class:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"

#include "Room.h"

#include "RoomGenerator.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class URoomGenerator : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    URoomGenerator(uint8 minX, uint8 maxX, uint8 minY, uint8 maxY);

    URoomGenerator() {};

    void Init(uint8 minX, uint8 maxX, uint8 minY, uint8 maxY);

    ARoom* GenerateRoom();

private:
    uint8 minX;
    uint8 maxX;
    uint8 minY;
    uint8 maxY;
};
```

Crash Report:

```
LoginId:a5fa88794956fc1be51808b1cb46e03b
EpicAccountId:e2ee81ebb2324ef4b67872a90edeabef

Assertion failed: [File:D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp] [Line: 2496] None is not being constructed with either NewObject, NewNamedObject or ConstructObject.

UE4Editor_Core!FWindowsErrorOutputDevice::Serialize() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\windows\windowserroroutputdevice.cpp:79]
UE4Editor_Core!FOutputDevice::LogfImpl() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\misc\outputdevice.cpp:71]
UE4Editor_Core!AssertFailedImplV() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\misc\assertionmacros.cpp:101]
UE4Editor_Core!FDebug::AssertFailed() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\misc\assertionmacros.cpp:449]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UObject::UObject() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\uobjectglobals.cpp:2496]
UE4Editor_Engine!AActor::AActor() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\actor.cpp:82]
UE4Editor_GreenPen_2449!ARoomGenerator::ARoomGenerator() [D:\Development\GreenPen\Source\GreenPen\RoomGenerator.cpp:10]
UE4Editor_GreenPen_2449!ADungeonGenerator::execGenerateDungeon() [D:\Development\GreenPen\Source\GreenPen\DungeonGenerator.h:15]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UFunction::Invoke() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\class.cpp:4643]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UObject::CallFunction() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:904]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UObject::ProcessContextOpcode() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:2314]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!ProcessLocalScriptFunction() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:974]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!ProcessScriptFunction<void (__cdecl*)(UObject *,FFrame &,void *)>() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:809]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!ProcessLocalFunction() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:1033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!ProcessLocalScriptFunction() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:974]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UObject::ProcessInternal() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:1058]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UFunction::Invoke() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\class.cpp:4643]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UObject::ProcessEvent() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\private\uobject\scriptcore.cpp:1464]
UE4Editor_Engine!AActor::ProcessEvent() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\actor.cpp:769]
UE4Editor_Engine!AActor::BeginPlay() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\actor.cpp:3383]
UE4Editor_Engine!AActor::DispatchBeginPlay() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\actor.cpp:3343]
UE4Editor_Engine!AWorldSettings::NotifyBeginPlay() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\worldsettings.cpp:253]
UE4Editor_Engine!AGameStateBase::HandleBeginPlay() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\gamestatebase.cpp:177]
UE4Editor_Engine!UWorld::BeginPlay() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\world.cpp:3948]
UE4Editor_Engine!UGameInstance::StartPlayInEditorGameInstance() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\gameinstance.cpp:413]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::CreatePIEGameInstance() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\playlevel.cpp:3341]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::PlayInEditor() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\playlevel.cpp:2466]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::StartQueuedPlayMapRequest() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\playlevel.cpp:1280]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::Tick() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\editorengine.cpp:1532]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UUnrealEdEngine::Tick() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\unrealedengine.cpp:403]
UE4Editor!FEngineLoop::Tick() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\launchengineloop.cpp:3967]
UE4Editor!GuardedMain() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\launch.cpp:168]
UE4Editor!GuardedMainWrapper() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\windows\launchwindows.cpp:145]
UE4Editor!WinMain() [d:\build\++ue4\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\windows\launchwindows.cpp:275]
UE4Editor!__scrt_common_main_seh() [d:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
kernel32
ntdll
```

DungeonGenerator.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"

#include "RoomGenerator.h"

#include "DungeonGenerator.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class GREENPEN_API ADungeonGenerator : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    ADungeonGenerator();

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "GreenPen Dungeon Generator")
        void GenerateDungeon();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
};
```

I get the error message "None is not being constructed with either NewObject, NewNamedObject or ConstructObject" when running the project... I would Like the debugger to enter the GenerateRoom function.

Comment: Blueprint: [link](https://imgur.com/lDXDyVy)

Comment: Could it be because you're using spawnActor with a non-actor class? If you want to spawn the generated by blueprint like that, it needs to be derived from AActor.

Comment: Also, can you show what's in the constructor for ARoomGenerator? That's where the error originates.

Comment: ```c++
URoomGenerator::URoomGenerator()
{  
 
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the Dungeongenerator class declaration... it is an actor right?

Answer (score 0):

Ah haaa...

this line says it all...

UE4Editor_GreenPen_2449!ARoomGenerator::ARoomGenerator([D:\Development\GreenPen\Source\GreenPen\RoomGenerator.cpp:10]

... thats on old file that I deleted, I did a clean and rebuild and everything started working again.

Thanks to Bas I was pointed in the right direction.